# Home network printer recommendations

Tags: networking, printing

I'm looking to buy a new printer to share between an Ubuntu 10.10 laptop and Windows Vista computer. I'm after something:

- fairly cheap (<=£100);
- with either wired or wireless networking;
- that works out of the box with Ubuntu;
- from any manufacturer.

I've seen a lot of recommendations for HP gear, but whenever I try to check compatibility of the latest bunch of HP Officejets on the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsPrintersHp), there's either no entry or just "needs retesting".

Can anyone suggest a good printer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I use HP printers at work, and so far I have not come across a model the does not work out of the box with Linux, and we are talking 10-15 different models.

Comment: Just to say I recently acquired a HP wireless printer (Photosmart C4580), which works in addition to the other wired models I have owned.

Comment: +1 for HP. They currently provide open-source driver support for over 2000 models of printer: http://hplipopensource.com/

Answer (score 4):

The [Open Printing](http://www.openprinting.org/printers/) site keeps a database of printers that work well with Linux. It's what I use before settling on a printer. I personally have had great successes with hp printers.

Answer (score 2):

I've found the best way to make sure a printer will work in Linux is to find a printer with native Postscript capabilities. They're slightly more expensive, but they tend to last forever. Beyond that, I've been very happy with HP. I love my [HP LasterJet 1320](http://www.openprinting.org/printer/HP/HP-LaserJet_1320); it was relatively cheap, has native PS, and can do double-sided prints to save on paper. I realize this doesn't match your "networked" requirement, but they may have a separate module for that, but then it probably wouldn't be as cheap. :)

Answer (score 1):

I recently acquired an HP Officejet 6000. It offers wired networking and works well with CUPS and HPLIP. My Device URI looks like this `hp:/net/Officejet_6000_E609a?ip=192.168.1.222` which gives fast wake-up from energy saving mode. For a reasonably fast and economical A4 inkjet printer, I certainly recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how much you use your printer. I recommend laser printers, they cost more, but they are much cheaper doing printing job(ink costs a lot).

HP printers are good using under linux.