# How to connect Brother MFC 255 CW wireless printer?

Tags: 11.04, printing

I just succesfully installed my printer driver. My printer is Brother MFC 255 CW. It works fine when I connected thorugh USB cable.

Then I tried to figure out how to connect using the wireless connection from the printer. Somehow ubuntu can't detect the printer signal.

This is so far the way what I did to try getting the printer connect to my laptop:

- System setting
- Printer
- Add Printer
- Network Printer
- Appsocket/HP Jet Direct, then set the host with the IP address that the printer provided and port number: 9100
- selecting the drive / installation
- after the additional installation finish I tried to print test page and nothing happen.

Is there any other way to figure out how to make the wireless working? Or maybe I did something wrong on the process...Please guys help me out......

Comment: Did the printer setup find the printer when selecting "Find" from the menu? see also [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19694/what-is-needed-for-a-networked-home-printer/19698#19698).

Answer (score 2):

I just went through this for the same printer.

If you haven't already, install the [Brother Drivers](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html#MFC-255CW) as Michal suggested. Both the LPR and Cupswrapper drivers. You say your printer works over USB, but not wireless. If so (or once you get your drivers installed):

Go to http://localhost:631/printers in browser to manage your printer. 
Click on your printer name, Administration and then Modify Printer. 
Select your printer under Networked Printers, click continue.
Enter the IP address for your printer, click continue.
Select your printer name with "Cups" version. 
Click Modify Printer and that should be it.

BTW, on that printer you can see your IP address by going into it's menu then selecting (5)Network, (1)TCP/IP, (2)IP Address.

Answer (score 1):

Don't select the printer manually. Wait a while and it will detect it automatically. If it detects two printers choose the one with the IP address.

Also install the cups wrapper and the lpr driver from the brother site.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to install [Brother drivers](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html#MFC-255CW). There are DEB packages available.