# How do I get a Brother 8065DN scanner to work over network?

Tags: 12.04, networking, 64-bit, scanner, brother

I've looked for instructions at the brother website but it seems terribly outdated. I can use it as a printer but not as a scanner in my office, but I need several machines with the ability to scan documents over the network.

Is there a way to get it to work as I describe?

Comment: What, if anything, have you tried so far? Can you report any error messages to add to your question?

Comment: Though for a different model brother, check this question and see if it helps http://askubuntu.com/questions/43354/how-to-connect-brother-mfc-255-cw-wireless-printer/98611#98611

Comment: here is the link I tried to no avail: http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/instruction_scn1b.html

Comment: What I'm really looking for is way to search for the scanner over the network, much in the same way I did with it to use the printer. Does anyone know how can I do this?

Comment: Following the procedure from the link above, my system can't find the scanner and I really don't know what to do now...

Comment: Ubuntu use dpkg, RPM is for other distros. Have you checked to make sure the scanner driver is installed (step 4-4 in your link)? Have you configured the network scanner and confirmed it's correct (steps 5-1 and 5-2)?

Comment: The brscan2 driver you need is at http://www.brother.com/cgi-bin/agreement/agreement.cgi?dlfile=http://www.brother.com/pub/bsc/linux/dlf/brscan2-0.2.5-1.i386.deb&lang=English_sane and the scan key tool you need is at http://www.brother.com/cgi-bin/agreement/agreement.cgi?dlfile=http://www.brother.com/pub/bsc/linux/dlf/brscan-skey-0.2.4-0.i386.deb&lang=English_lpr   Also, have you already got the printer drivers installed and printer working correctly?