# Ubuntu doesn't find installed drivers for Brother MFC-255CW printer

Tags: 12.04, drivers, printing, find, brother

I am brand new to Ubuntu, but I a fairly experienced computer user.  Following the instructions provided by the Brother website, I was able to install the drivers (CUPSwrapper and LPR) for the MFC-255CW printer locally connected to the computer.  When looking for the drivers via the terminal, the drivers are found.  However, when I attempt to add the printer, Ubuntu searches for but does not find the drivers.  What am I doing wrong?  Has anyone experienced this same problem?  Are there instructions, other than those on the Brother website, for installing the specified printer?  Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link for the [drivers](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html#MFC-255CW) for the Brother MFC-255CW printer for Linux. I was taking a look at [this AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43354/how-to-connect-brother-mfc-255-cw-wireless-printer) and, although this refers to 11.04, it seems like following the answers mentioned in this question should get your printer working. You need to install both the `LPR` and `Cupswrapper` drivers in the link.

Additionally, there is an [UbuntuForums thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1256630) that details how to do this. I would check this out if you want step by step instructions.

### Wireless Setup

You have to go to `http://localhost:631/printers` in your browser to set up the printer for wireless because CUPS comes with this web interface to add the printer. Here are some general instructions for this:

1. Click on your printer name, `Administration` and then `Modify Printer`.
2. Select your printer under Networked Printers, click `Continue`.
3. Enter the IP address for your printer, click `Continue`.
4. Select your printer name with "Cups" version.
5. Click `Modify Printer` and that should be it.

**Edit**:
This will install only the LPR driver. While following instructions from the Brother website to install the CUPSwrapper driver, you will get an error. To fix this, copy the `mfc255cwcupswrapper-1.1.3-1.i386.deb` to another directory location and name it `mfc255cwcupswrapper.deb`(in other words, delete the version number). Going back to the instructions, change the terminal input from

`dpkg -i --force-all mfc255cwcupswrapper-1.1.3-1.i386.deb`

to

`dpkg -i --force-all mfc255cwcupswrapper.deb`

in order to reflect the new name of the driver file and Ubuntu was able to find the MRC255CW driver.

Comment: Only the LPR driver was installed.  However, while following instructions from the Brother website to install the CUPSwrapper driver I got an error.  I copied mfc255cwcupswrapper-1.1.3-1.i386.deb to another directory location and named it mfc255cwcupswrapper.deb, no version number.  Once I did this, and changed the terminal input from "dpkg  -i  --force-all  mfc255cwcupswrapper-1.1.3-1.i386.deb" to "dpkg  -i  --force-all  mfc255cwcupswrapper.deb" in order to reflect the new name of the driver file, everything executed properly and Ubuntu was able to find the MRC255CW driver.  My printer works.