# How do I get Samba and CUPS installed onto Ubuntu Unity 11.10 and recognize my network printers

Tags: 11.10, networking, printing

I have a HP930C printer installed on an older machine with Windows 2000.  I had it working up Ubuntu 9.10 and also have a network printer Lexmark X7600 on a wired LAN connection.

I was able to get them working with SAMBA and was able to print to them.  I won't hook the Lexmark to work with WiFi because of security concerns.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

By default Ubuntu lets you install local or network printers. Just open *Printers* from the system dropdown menu on the top right:

[image]

In the configuration window choose *Add* to add a new printer

[image]

To add a network printer choose this in the next window

[image]

The selection depends on the method your printer share is set up on the printer server. This may be SAMBA on the Windows side but also other protocols are supported. See also [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/19698/3940) on how to set up a shared network printer in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu likely ships with the necessary packages. If not, make sure you install `smbclient`, `libsmbclient`, `samba` and maybe even `system-config-samba`. Ubuntu 9.10 is no longer supported so you might have trouble accessing these packages in the package manager in Ubuntu 9.10, it's best to install the latest version, but I guess if you're patient enough you could wait it out until the next LTS is released.