# Where must I click in Printing Settings to pull up Server settings?

Tags: networking, server, printing

I am trying to publish a network printer.  I have tried right clicking everywhere but it does not offer the server option. I remember from a year ago having to do this and I found it then but this is a new 12.04 install and I just cannot find it.  Is there a command line option?

Comment: see if that helps: http://askubuntu.com/questions/19694/what-is-needed-for-a-networked-home-printer

Answer (score 0):

To see a "Server" button try:

```
system-config-printer
```

in the Terminal.

bye

Comment: Thank you.  I had already tried that but it brings up the same window as the GUI and my question remains:  Where exactly do I right click?

Comment: I have just noticed the reply from @takkat - thank you very much - it is probably fixed thanks to your screenshot - I had not seen tbat option at the top of the screen - too late now to try - I'll revert tomorrow [France time]

Comment: @takkat thank you. The printer is now visible on the network.  I revisited an old 11.04 Ubuntu system and noticed that Server was an option on the title bar of the window.  In 12.04 this has gone and it is now an option on the very top title bar of the screen and which only becomes visible when you hover there.  This is definitely a retrograde step so if anyone knows how to bring this to the attdntion of the developers please do so.