# Printer Add button not enabled

Tags: 12.04, printing

I am trying to set-up a network printer on my system.

Navigated to System Setting>>Printing and viola the Add button out there is disabled.

When i troubleshooted using Help it said that the CUPS print spooler does not appear to be running. To correct this, choose System->Administration->Services from the main menu and look for 'cups' service.

Please tell me what to do in order to add a printer[image: Following is the ScreenShot of what i was doing]

Comment: Does this help you: http://askubuntu.com/a/19698/3940 ?

Comment: No, The settings option is not enabled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to open a terminal (or alt-f2 to display command execution prompt) and run

```
sudo system-config-printer
```

and check if you can add a printer from there.

Comment: No, I can't. The same window opens up which is shown in the screenshot above

Comment: Why is add button not enabled :/

Comment: maybe because the cups server isn't running, try browsing to http://localhost:631/

Comment: and yes you are right, it is not running, i tried to install it as well but it failed

Comment: I mean if you paste that address into your browser shows anything? Because that's the cups service port, just to check if it's running

Comment: it says: ops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost:631
Suggestions:
Try reloading: localhost:­631

Comment: on terminal if you do `sudo apt-get install cups` what you get?

Comment: i get>> Package cups is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  cups-filters

E: Package 'cups' has no installation candidate

Comment: these packages are already installed>> cups-bsd , cups-client     ,
cups-common     ,
cups-filters     ,
cups-pk-helper     ,
cups-ppdc

Answer (score 4):

Open a web browser and navigate to `http://localhost:631`. This is the *real* interface to your printing system. If you want to do anything fancy, do it here. You are eliminating a lot of potential error stemming from bugs and flaws in the gnome printer dialog. Mostly the gnome dialog is just oversimplifying on some advanced functions.

If you don't see a website on `localhost:631` your cups daemon (the printing system) is not running at all. Make sure it is installed.

Comment: no, localhost:631 doesn't show up anything

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install cups
```

*#my CUPS was not installed after upgrading to 18.04, after i did this printers showed right up just had to close and reopen the printer app*

Answer (score 0):

Modify the contents of /etc/environment file from

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
http_proxy="http://111.125.139.199:8105/"
https_proxy="https://111.125.139.199:0/"
ftp_proxy="ftp://111.125.139.199:24/"
socks_proxy="socks://111.125.139.199:0/"
```

to

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
```

Comment: very unusual - maybe you can explain why you had a proxy setup - surely that would affect other network related stuff by removing the proxy?

Comment: well, i was having chat conversation on stackexchange network with someone regarding an issue on my system and he asked me to do that :/

Comment: well yeah, this obviously was the reason, since the printer setup utilities use http connections to localhost to configure the printing system, and you where redirecting all http traffic over a server in ... India... btw. are you aware of that? If not, who asked you to do this?

Comment: well i don't remeber his name :P