# How do I add a network printer in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: networking, printing, administration

I know the name and the IP address of a network printer, but I can't seem to be able to search by IP address or name.

Ubuntu developers love to move things around to make it difficult for users, so now with Ubuntu 12.04 I can only go on `Application -> System Tools -> System Settings -> Printers`, click on `Network` and a list of printers appears. Too bad the one I want to add isn't there.

How do I do it?

[Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu#Printing_from_Ubuntu) it suggests `System -> Administration -> Printing`, which simply doesn't exist.

Comment: Please confirm that which printer you want to add whether it is on network or not?

Comment: It is in my network, yes. I added all my printers when I had a previous release of Ubuntu and it worked just like it's described in link above. Now I can't do anything with the way they rearranged stuff in the system settings.

Comment: try to ping the printers ip.if you are able to ping the printer than you should check your settings.

Comment: Yes, I am able to ping the printer. What should I do next? I remember that in the past I could search by IP address or printer name, select the driver, etc. Here I can't do anything at all...

Comment: Now run this command sudo system-config-printer  and follow the steps I hop this will work for you.

Comment: In Dash search for Printers, then click add printer. in the uri box enter the ip address of your printer directly. Follow the wizard with the various settings.

Comment: `Dash` is for Unity, right? I use gnome and the only thing related to printing is what I mentioned above.   In any case, running `system-config-printer` from a shell worked! :) Thanks!

Comment: This may help you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/19694/what-is-needed-for-a-networked-home-printer

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Type this in your terminal

```
system-config-printer
```

Comment: You don't really need to be root for this so you can remove "sudo"

Comment: @hydrarulz - Not necessarily true. Without sudo, you might get a "Privleges are required to get a list of available devices" prompt when attempting to add a device.