# Is it possible to connect (wireless) a usb printer to WLAN?

Tags: wireless, printing

I've been wanting to be able to print through an HP PSC 1315 printer over wifi (printer has no wifi; it works with usb!). So I just was thinking about connecting a wifi dongle to it. Would that be possible solution?

I've just read this: http://www.linux-magazine.com/Online/Features/AirPrint but I am not sure (1) if this is relevant to my situation and (2) whether this could work without an always running machine.

Hope you could help me out on this. Thanks

Comment: You also might find answers to the following question helpful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/19694/what-is-needed-for-a-networked-home-printer

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're suggesting plugging a wifi dongle into the USB port of a printer. This won't work as you'll need a USB host port to accept the dongle (and the printer will need to know how to use it). No. No go.

However you can buy little wireless print-servers that are intended to do what you're suggesting. They're actually little Linux boxes that connect to the printer and the network.

Here's one: [Edimax PS-1206U for a snitch over £22](http://www.extak.com/product/224491/Edimax-PS-1206U-Print-Server%2C-Ethernet-L)

---

Connecting it to a computer and sharing it is an option but, as you've already worked out, that requires you leave your computer on all the time. That's going to use a lot more power than a little RISC 0.5A box.

Comment: For the first option, it will still need to be connected by wire, right?

What if (for the 2nd option) I want it connected to only one computer? For example, what If I wanted it to use it only for a particular computer and not always turned on? Is there a possible wireless connection?

Comment: Some of those boxes (including the one I linked to) have USB-A female host ports, some have USB-B male ports so you plug it directly into the back of the printer... I would imagine the first is better as some USB-B Female ports on printers are quite obstructed. I imagine they also have separate power supplies.

Comment: The second option is always going to require the computer it's connected to to be turned on.