# Setting up network printer Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: networking, printing

New Ubuntu 13.10 Laptop

File Sharing is working fine.

According to one post:

1. Go to the Printers applet
2. Press the Add printer button
3. Select Network Printer
4. Select Find Network Printer

Problem, when I select [Add printer] I do not have the [Find Network Printer] option.

What is missing?

Comment: not yet tested on 13.10 but have a look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/19694/what-is-needed-for-a-networked-home-printer

Comment: Try logging in to the CUPS interface and add the printer from there. http://localhost:631/admin

Answer (score 0):

When you open **Printing** by searching through the dash. You'll get printing dialogue box. And once you click **Add**, then you should see something like below;

[image]

Expand **Network Printer** by selecting that little arrow, then type the IP on the Host.

Once again, if you do not see such option, please post a screen of what you see.

**Useful Link:** [Network Printing with Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu)

Comment: You fail to EXACTLY state where to get to the dialogue you show. Need menu steps. I'm using GNOME Desktop.

Comment: Read the answer carefully. As I've stared assuming you've located printing icon from the Dash menu. Click the Dash home from the menu. And its is indeed for GNOME. I've mentioned exactly what you need. :)