# Compatiple printer list

Tags: 12.04, printing

I have tried to search for a printer to use with my new install and so far, I haven't found a sure thing. Does anyone have a list of compatible printers to use with Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/102995/what-is-the-best-printer-for-ubuntu or http://askubuntu.com/questions/11160/home-network-printer-recommendations

Answer (score 0):

According to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Printers, [there](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsPrinters) is list of compatible printers.